# Rails: page keeps loading during "after_commit execution"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After creating a database entry I want to do some stuff with it but still be able to navigate the page while that code executes. Additionally I want to see how the newly created object changes over that time.

So I did something like this:

```
class Penguin < ActiveRecord::Base

after_commit :do_stuff, on: [:create]

      def do_stuff
        #self.update(status, "doing stuff")   results in an infinite loop,  see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14493
        self.update_column(:status, "doing stuff") #fix skips callback

        puts "I do sleeping so here we go..."
        sleep(10)
        puts "...done"

        #self.update(status = "done")   results in an infinite loop, see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14493
        self.update_column(:status, "done") #fix skips callback
      end
end
```

Which doesn't seem to work, the page keeps loading until those 10 seconds are over. What am I doing wrong?

**I'm using Rails 4.2.5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Rails process will hang until completion of model callbacks. In otherwords, your page won't load until your after_commit code has been fully processed.

You should consider using [background jobs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html), to push this processing into the background after the page has loaded. I can highly recommend [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) for this (although a bit out of date now, [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) will really help you get started with background jobs).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
bin/rails generate job penguins_update
```

Then in `config/application.rb` you can add any adapter like sidekick, resque

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

Then `app/jobs/penguins_update.rb`

```
class PenguinsUpdateJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  before_enqueue do |job|
    penguin.update_column(:status, "doing stuff")  
  end

  def perform(penguin)
    penguin.update_column(:status, "done")
  end
end
```

Now you can call it by

```
PenguinsUpdateJob.perform_later(penguin) #this will queue it
```

or

if you want to  process immediately without sending to the queue:

```
PenguinsUpdateJob.perform_now(penguin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I looked into background jobs and decided to use [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

If someone else is new to this and wants to try it, don't forget:

> **Rails 4** replace script/delayed_job with bin/delayed_job

Took me a while until I decided to read that section again thoroughly ;)